# An Extremely Long Equation with Fraction

Tags: equations

I don't know what to do in order to fit this equation in the document, because it's so long. 
Help will be very appreciated, and also if someone have any idea how to simplify this equation it's will be very helpful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} a(t) =
\frac{6.67384\times 10^{-11}\times 5.972\times 10^{24}}
{ \left[149.6\sin (\frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6})-0.908
\left( 2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2 + 9.479 \times 10^{-6}(t+
\left| t-379.189\right| -379.189)\right)\right]^2+
\left[149.638 - 0.418(2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2 + 9.479
\times 10^{-6}(t+\left| t-379.189\right| -379.189))- 149.6 \cos
\left( \frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6}
\right)\right]^2+ 0.0002831}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Your equation doesn't compile (even before I edited its presentation)

Comment: There are single left or right delimiters, so it can't compile

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time posting a quastion here, I didn't know I need to add the essentials of a TeX document. Here is the new version with all of the essentials:

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article} \begin{document} \begin{equation} a(t) = \frac{6.67384\times 10^{-11}\times 5.972\times 10^{24}}{ 
\left[149.6\sin (\frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6)-0.908 \left(
2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2 + 9.479 \times 10^{-6}(t+\left| t-379.189\right|
-379.189)\right)\right]^2+ \left[149.638 -  0.418(2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2
 + 9.479 \times 10^{-6}(t+\left| t-379.189\right| -379.189))- 149.6 
\cos \left( \frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6} \right)\right]^2+ 0.0002831} \end{equation}\end{document}

Comment: "There are single left or right delimiters"' could you explain me please, what does it mean?

Comment: In future, please edit the question don't put code in comments (as you see it doesn't really work:-) I did it this time.

Comment: Your code looks like it has quite a few errors, especially in terms of the scope of the numerator and denominator parts of the `\frac` directives. Having no idea what the final result is supposed to look like, it's hard to give specific advice on how to fix your code.

Comment: In particular, the fragment `\sin (\frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6)` looks problematic. Should it maybe be `\sin (\frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

[image]

(You are obviously free to come up with snazzier symbols than "B", "C", and "D".)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Let
\begin{equation} 
a(t) =
\frac{6.67384\cdot 10^{-11}\cdot 5.972\cdot 10^{24}}{B}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
B&= \bigl[149.6\sin C-0.908D \bigr]^2\\
&\quad+ \bigl[149.638 - 0.418D- 149.6 \cos C\bigr]^2 + 0.0002831\,,\\
C &= 3\pi t/(47\cdot 10^6)
\shortintertext{and}
D &= 2.5\cdot 10^{-8} t^2 + 9.479 \cdot 10^{-6}\bigl(t+
\lvert t-379.189\rvert -379.189\bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask about the typeset result but the input generates errors (which means usually the pdf is not worth looking at except possibly for debugging)

```
Runaway argument?
{ \left [149.6\sin (\frac {3\pi t}{47\times 10^6)-0.908 \left ( 2.5\times \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frac.
```

Which means that you have a missing `}`

having fixed that, it's simply too wide to read, I'd do something like the following although you may choose different subterms to pull out depending on any aspect you want to highlight,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a(t) =
\frac{6.67384\times 10^{-11}\times 5.972\times 10^{24}}
{149.6\sin (\alpha)}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
\alpha&=\frac{3\pi t}{\beta}\\
\beta&=47\times 10^6-0.908
( 2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2 +\\
&\qquad 9.479 \times 10^{-6}(t+
| t-379.189| -379.189))]^2+\\
&\qquad [149.638 - 0.418(2.5\times 10^{-8} t^2 + \\
&\qquad 9.479
\times 10^{-6}(t+|t-379.189| -379.189))- \\
&\qquad 149.6 \cos
( \frac{3\pi t}{47\times 10^6})]^2+ 0.0002831
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I fixed it now, but it's different than what you wrote.